# I'm trying to build with yarn but I get a strange ng2-pdfjs-viewer error

Tags: angular, yarnpkg, yarn-lock.json

Yarn rifled through my Angular project and found the versions needed to run locally.

But for some reason when it executes on the build server, I get this :

> 12:22:29 yarn install v1.22.21 12:22:30 [1/4] Resolving packages...
> 12:22:30 warning Lockfile has incorrect entry for
> "ng2-pdfjs-viewer@^7.0.0". Ignoring it. 12:22:31 error Couldn't find
> any versions for "ng2-pdfjs-viewer" that matches "^7.0.0"

The relevant section of my yarn.lock file is :

> ng2-pdfjs-viewer@^7.0.0:   version "13.2.2"   resolved
> "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/ng2-pdfjs-viewer/-/ng2-pdfjs-viewer-13.2.2.tgz#350973cf4acf6efbffff763f9fd3f80133cc8fbc"
> integrity
> sha512-CewnBnWfWb1+2S/SdCOGTsfw11LZWS0E5DqYiowksbC8s2Gcv3unsK8DtEvd/efb3mfT7UlZKX4aUPrjqwe+Ug==
> dependencies:
> tslib "^2.3.0"

Fwiw, ng2-pdfjs-viewer does not seem to have a version 7.0.0 available, but it does have a 13.2.2 version available and something starts downloading when I paste that link into my browser.

The yarn version that is working is 1.22.21.

Any suggestions about how to get past the error ?